# dotnet-counters ps doesn't show any processes

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnetcorecli

I have .NET Core 2.2 application and wanted to use [dotnet-counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters) to get some data about GC. Unfortunately dotnet-counters doesn't see my app (.NET core process) for some reason. When I run

```
dotnet-counters ps
```

It returns nothing (my .NET core application is running of course). I use .NET Core version 2.2.8 and dotnet-counters version 3.1.57502. I tried both standalone and Framework dependend version of application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The diagnostic tools (`dotnet counters`, `dotnet trace`, `dotnet dump`) rely on new features of the runtime exposing the necessary interfaces. These are only present on .NET Core 3.0 or higher.

This means that a .NET Core 2.2 application cannot be monitored / diagnosed with these tools. You will need to update your application to .NET Core 3.0+